# VBA 7.1 Backwards Compatibility

Tags: c#, vba, excel

I am developing some VBA code using VBA 7.1 with excel 2016 as part of a larger enterprise application (not primarily in excel). The macros are run from a C# application and used to export data in the form of spreadsheets. I am looking for a good guide as to what versions of excel these macros will run properly on, and where I can look for changes that could potentially cause my code to break. I developed it using excel 2016, how backwards compatible will this be?

I would like to make it compatible as far back as the 2010 excel version if possible.

Comment: VBA itself is largely unchanged over the years - only host-application-specific changes have occurred, but I'm not aware of any guide which lays out the versions which support each method: you will need to check them individually.  How far back in the Excel timeline do you need to support?

Comment: One crazy thing: forms in excel2016 are 8 pt less in heights. I check excel version and substract 8 pts for versions lower than 16 to copy with that. Made me crazy to find out....

Comment: @bohmbac2 any links you can share how to do it from C# and 2016 please i.e. running macro/vb scripts for 2016 excelsheet from C#

Answer (score 0):

If you need compatibility with VBA6 and VBA7, this is a good example how to achieve it through compiler constants:

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA6 Then
    Sub RunTheApp()
        Debug.Print "VBA6"
    End Sub
#ElseIf VBA7 Then
    Sub RunTheApp()
        Debug.Print "VBA7"
    End Sub
#Else
    Sub RunTheApp()
        Debug.Print "You cannot come here from TestMe()"
    End Sub
#End If

Sub TestMe()
    RunTheApp
End Sub
```

Once you try to run the `TestMe` module, it will print `VBA6` or `VBA7`, depending on your system.

[MSDN - Compiler Constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/compiler-constants)

In general, VBA7 has compability for 64bit environment. Here is the MSDN article for the differences between these two - [Compatibility between the 32-bit and 64-bit Versions of Office 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691831%28loband%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#odc_office2010_Compatibility32bit64bit_IntroducingVBA7CodeBase) It is a good idea to read it, if you are using external functions that are embedded in dynamic linked libraries.